# click on expand button with identified text name

Tags: css, xpath, robotframework

I want to click on an expand button which beside it the text is `test`.
[image]

outer HTML

```
<td class="ant-table-cell ant-table-cell-fix-left ant-table-cell-with-append" style="position: sticky; left: 0px;"><span style="padding-left: 0px;" class="ant-table-row-indent indent-level-0"></span><button type="button" class="ant-table-row-expand-icon ant-table-row-expand-icon-collapsed" aria-label="Expand row"></button>test</td>
```

I have tried this XPath and it is not working:

```
//button[@aria-label='Expand row']//span[text()="test"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it now:

```
//td[text()='test']//button[@class='ant-table-row-expand-icon ant-table-row-expand-icon-collapsed']
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some handy google chrome extensions that are useful for finding awkward xpaths. I quite like TruePath, can right click on elements, copy across and try a few iterations of xpaths very quickly. I know this isn't what you are looking for and issue is solved but it's one of the tools I use everyday and might help for similar in future.

Comment: I just installed TruePath, right click on the button and get RelativeXpath, the truepath dialogue is open, I did not see any good info being captured. I was using selectorsHub just now to try out different set of XPath till it prompts me found 1 element.

Comment: Theyre not perfect and at times they do not work for what we need and I don't think there will ever be a substitute for  finding the right xpath manually when needed- but for fast iterative work they are better than alternatives like the browser generated xpaths e.g in Chrome. Selectorshub I also like especially as it copies directly to the clipboard